# Posting to Twitter from Rails app with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, omniauth

I’m set up devise and omni-auth for both twitter and Facebook and now I’d like to allow users post a tweet or Facebook post from my app. I’m looked all over and confused on where to start for this. For right now I just want it to be a dummy post, doesn’t need to include anything from my rails app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post tweets on Twitter you can go for **[Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)**.
Read the documentation **[here](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter)**

For Facebook you can go for **[Koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala)**
Read the documentation **[here](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki)**

Comment: I've looked through this but still confused on how to post from an individual user that is currently authenticated in my app

Comment: Documentation clearly gives instructions on how to configure and post. What have you tried so far? Show the relevant code which is not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an example app for posting on twitter then you may check it out here with a working app posting on twitter:
https://github.com/railscasts/359-twitter-integration

Hope you may find it useful